# Passing data ArrayList from Plugin to helper class in Tv-Browser API

Tags: java, plugins

How to pass data ArrayList from Plugin to helper class in Tv-Browser API. The helper class is not a part of Tv-Browser API, instead it is a simple JFrame.
I have tried sending the arrayList in the constructor of my custom JFrame, but just gets stuck when try to get Data.
And plugin even siezes to work and show at all

Comment: Please provide detailed information and ideally the code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method of making all helper classes as inner classes was wrong and bad design.
I was using netBeans, so used Jar file in the project dist folder and it worked just fine.
Explanation: The classes were compiled, paths used by Netbeans so it had the right location of classes and lib. also the right Jar file in dist folder.

I have put all helper classes in the Plugin class as inner classes. And it has worked just fine. No need to send information between classes. As Plugin is a relatively small class, this approach has worked just fine